# how to parse this json data ? and store it directly in database and then display it in listview

Tags: android, json

//This my__json__data 
json ////This is main json object

```
{
  "cityMasterEntity":
--This is array
 [
    {
      "CityId": 1,
      "CityName": "Ahmedabad",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "StateId": 6,
      "StateName": "Gujarat\u000d\u000a",
      "UpdatedDate": null
    },
    {
      "CityId": 3,
      "CityName": "Rajkot",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "StateId": 6,
      "StateName": "Gujarat\u000d\u000a",
      "UpdatedDate": null
    },
    {
      "CityId": 2,
      "CityName": "Surat",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "StateId": 6,
      "StateName": "Gujarat\u000d\u000a",
      "UpdatedDate": null
    }`enter code here`
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yash you should have added that to the other question

Comment: Too few elements to know what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far... We don't even know the language (javascript?) or how to want to display it (html?).

Comment: Why did you ask second question? You should have added in the same.

Comment: My problem is here :NUll POINTER exception is coming 
    citymaster = newrummy.getJSONArray(CITYARRAY);///
    for (int i = 0; i < citymaster.length(); i++) {

     newrummy = citymaster.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: @yash_5111 then `citymaster` is null . I would check by logging the json.

Comment: yes it coming null i have also checked suggest some solution i m new to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{   // json object node
  "cityMasterEntity":[ // json array
    {                  // json object node
      "CityId": 1
```

To parse

```
JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("yourString");
JSONArray city = jb.getJSONArray("cityMasterEntity");
for(int i=0;i<city.length();i++)
{
   JSONObject jb1 =(JSONObject) city.getJSONObject(i);
   int id = jb1.getInt("CityId");
   String name = jb1.getString("CityName");  
   ...// similarl for name and others
}
```

To store it in database you can use sqlite. To display you ca use a listview.

Edit:

```
 class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
  {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String _response= null;
        try
        {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.clubrummy.in/MobileWCF/RummyService/GetMasterDetail");  
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
                Log.i(".......",_response);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return _response;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result!=null)
    {
        try
        {
        JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray city = jb.getJSONArray("cityMasterEntity");
        for(int i=0;i<city.length();i++)
        {
           JSONObject jb1 =(JSONObject) city.getJSONObject(i);
           int id = jb1.getInt("CityId");
           String name = jb1.getString("CityName");  
           Log.i("Name is",""+name);
        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
    }
```

Edit 2:

In fact you can parse json store data in database in doInbackground itself. Update ui in onPostExecute

```
  class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
  {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String _response= null;
        try
        {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.clubrummy.in/MobileWCF/RummyService/GetMasterDetail");  
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
                Log.i(".......",_response);
                if(_response!=null)
                {

                    JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(_response);
                    JSONArray city = jb.getJSONArray("cityMasterEntity");
                    for(int i=0;i<city.length();i++)
                    {
                       JSONObject jb1 =(JSONObject) city.getJSONObject(i);
                       int id = jb1.getInt("CityId");
                       String name = jb1.getString("CityName");  
                       Log.i("Name is",""+name);
                    }
                }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

  }
  }
```

Also if loading data from database takes time use loaders.

Comment: dont know i din't down voted it. may by mistake it has been done.

Comment: @yash_5111 your response is null. So you need to check how you download the json.

Comment: @yash_5111 check the edit it should work.

Comment: @Raghunandan doesnt know who was downvoted.But these answer was useful.

Comment: Thanks @ Raghunandan your was very useful

Comment: @Raghunandan : on button click i want to fetch json from database and display in listview  suggested me with suitable answer and i m using cursor adapter

Comment: @yash_5111 post a new question with relevant details